# Control/retrieve ordinate position in TimelinePlot

Tags: visualization, time-series

I want to make a family tree. My approach is to use the birth year to structure the tree in abscissa. The issue is the ordinate positions of the according person. It may change when the family tree is update or changed.
My code is:

```
 TimelinePlot[{
  {Labeled[Interval[{DatePlus[Today, -15000 ], Today}], "dad"], 
   Labeled[Interval[{DatePlus[Today, -14500 ], Today}], "mother"],
   Labeled[Interval[{DatePlus[Today, -5000 ], Today}], "me"], 
   Labeled[Interval[{DatePlus[Today, -6000 ], Today}], "sister"]},
  {Labeled[Interval[{DatePlus[Today, -4500 ], Today}], "partner"],
   Labeled[Interval[{DatePlus[Today, -600 ], Today}], "son 1"], 
   Labeled[Interval[{DatePlus[Today, -400 ], Today}], 
    "son 2"]}, {Labeled[Interval[{DatePlus[Today, -6800 ], Today}], 
    "bro inlaw"], 
   Labeled[Interval[{DatePlus[Today, -1800 ], Today}], "nephew 1"], 
   Labeled[Interval[{DatePlus[Today, -1200 ], Today}], "nephew 2"]}
  }, Epilog -> {
   Arrow[{{AbsoluteTime[DatePlus[Today, -15000 ]], 
      1}, {AbsoluteTime[DatePlus[Today, -5000 ]], 4}}],
   Arrow[{{AbsoluteTime[DatePlus[Today, -15000 ]], 
      1}, {AbsoluteTime@DatePlus[Today, -6000 ], 3}}],
   Arrow[{{AbsoluteTime[DatePlus[Today, -6800 ]], 
      8}, {AbsoluteTime@DatePlus[Today, -1800 ], 9}}],
   Arrow[{{AbsoluteTime[DatePlus[Today, -6800 ]], 
      8}, {AbsoluteTime@DatePlus[Today, -1200 ], 10}}],
   Arrow[{{AbsoluteTime[DatePlus[Today, -5000 ]], 
      4}, {AbsoluteTime@DatePlus[Today, -600 ], 6}}],
   Arrow[{{AbsoluteTime[DatePlus[Today, -5000 ]], 
      4}, {AbsoluteTime@DatePlus[Today, -400 ], 7}}]
   }]
```

[image]
I use the arrows to indicate the parenthood. This arrow needs ordinate points for the parent and offspring (abscissa in known). Is it possible to set ordinate position for a given interval? Alternatively, is it possible to retrive the coordinates of a given interval (e.g. "partner")? Imagine I get another son or daughter. It all needs a new setup by hand right now.

Comment: if you sort the first argument of `TimelinePlot` by birthdates (that is, use `Map[List]@SortBy[First]@(Join@@{{...},{...}})` as the first argument)  it will be easier to associate dates with vertical coordinates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `input` equal to the first argument of `TimelinePlot` in OP:

```
sortedinput = SortBy[#[[1, 1]] &] @ (Join @@ input);

birthdaysandorders = Association[
   MapIndexed[Last[#] -> {AbsoluteTime @ #[[1, 1, 1]], #2[[1]]} &, sortedinput]];

children = Association[{"dad" -> {"sister", "me"}, "me" -> {"son 1", "son 2"}, 
    "bro inlaw" -> {"nephew 1", "nephew 2"}}];

arrows = Join @@ KeyValueMap[Arrow /@ 
  Thread[{birthdaysandorders[#], birthdaysandorders /@ #2}, List, {2}] &, children];

TimelinePlot[List /@ sortedinput, Epilog -> {Arrowheads[Medium], arrows}]
```

[image]

You can add additional arrows as easily:

```
TimelinePlot[List /@ sortedinput, 
 Epilog -> {Arrowheads[Medium], arrows, 
  Dashed, Red, Arrow[birthdaysandorders /@ {"mother", "son 2"}]}]
```

[image]

Ordinate position of `"partner"`:

```
Last @ birthdaysandorders["partner"]
```

> 6

Comment: That is what I was looking for. I need some time to figure out what you did in detail and how it works. A lot of programming learning for me in this answer. Then I can test if it works when adding more people.